# css media works in desktop browser developer mode but not on actual iphone 6s

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

The following media query works on desktop browsers in developer mode but does not work on mobile browsers on actual iphone 6S.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){

div.woof_sid_auto_shortcode .woof_container {
    background-color: fuchsia !important;
}
}
```

The url is: https://susustudio.info/load/shop888/   it's WordPress
I have this in the header.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2.0">`

Any ideas why this isn't working?

DubVader's comment is the solution. I don't have a checkmark beside it to toggle as accepted.  I changed my query as below:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){

div.woof_sid_auto_shortcode .woof_container {
    background-color: fuchsia !important;
}
}
```

Comment: I think maybe you need to use (max-device-width: 667px), not height.

Comment: Have added as a solution so you can toggle as answered for others.  Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (max-device-width: 667px), not height.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){

div.woof_sid_auto_shortcode .woof_container {
    background-color: fuchsia !important;
}
}
```